# (php) could not connect to the MSSQL 2008 on the vps server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a google vps server with a database MSSQL 2008 r2 . on a computer at home I can not connect to the database with php script but when filled ip,port tool "SQL Server Management Studio" it connects successfully . please help me fix it, I seem to be going crazy :(

[Image SQL Server Management Studio 2008 r2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz0F5.jpg)

here is my php code

```
<?php
$myserver = "xx.xx.xx.xx,1433";
$myuser = "sa";
$mypass = "123456";
$mydb = "muonline"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myserver, $myuser, $mypass)
  or die("couldn't connect to sql server on $myserver"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($mydb, $dbhandle)
  or die("couldn't open database $mydb"); 

//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

I tried to change $myserver with the value:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:1433
xx.xx.xx.xx\\instance-1,1433
xx.xx.xx.xx:1433\\instance-1
xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx\\instance-1
```

always notify Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server

Comment: You "have a vps server [...] on a computer at home"? You mean you have a virtual machine, I assume?

Comment: I use server google vps. I'm sorry bad english

Comment: Ah, so php and the sql server operate on different systems: php at your home computer and the sql server at a google system. And this looks like you also use an MS-Windows platform on your home computer. OK, thanks for clarifying that.